# Remove keys that don't contain any of the values in a set

Tags: scala

```
val s = Set("blue", "orange")
val m = Map("product_orange_123" -> 1, "prodoct_blue_123" -> 2, "product_green_123" -> 5, "product_blue_887" -> 7)
```

I want to remove any key in the map that doesn't contain any of the values in the set s.

Expected output:

```
("product_orange_123" -> 1, "prodoct_blue_123" -> 2, "product_blue_887" -> 7)
```

Comment: can you please share the expected output as well.

Comment: How do you even compile `val m = Map("product_orange_123", "prodoct_blue_123", "product_green_123", "product_blue_887")`? Map has type `Map[Key, Value]`.

Comment: @ipoteka fixed sorry.

Comment: I would recommend you to make a class like this, to use as keys in your map: `case class Product(val color: String, val id: Int)`. You could then filter your map more easily by not having to deal with the `String.contains` method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well I guess what you meant

**Filter keys of map that does not contains any value of the set**

```
m.filterKeys(key => s.exists(key.contains(_)) )
```

this will do

Answer (score 1):

## Set extends Function1

Collect in action

```
m.collect { case (k, v) if s(k.split("_")(1)) => k -> v }
```

filterKeys in action

```
m.filterKeys(key => s(key.split("_")(1)))
```

filter in action

```
m.filter { case (k, _) => s(k.split("_")(1)) }
```

## Explanation

`Set` extends `Function1` and set instance can be directly applied to the a key to check if it exists in the set.

```
scala> val s = Set("blue", "orange")
s: scala.collection.immutable.Set[String] = Set(blue, orange)

scala> s("blue")
res0: Boolean = true

scala> s("apple")
res1: Boolean = false

scala> val s = Set("blue", "orange")
s: scala.collection.immutable.Set[String] = Set(blue, orange)

scala> val m = Map("product_orange_123" -> 1, "prodoct_blue_123" -> 2, "product_green_123" -> 5, "product_blue_887" -> 7)
m: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(product_orange_123 -> 1, prodoct_blue_123 -> 2, product_green_123 -> 5, product_blue_887 -> 7)

scala> m.collect { case (k, v) if s(k.split("_")(1)) => k -> v }
res2: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(product_orange_123 -> 1, prodoct_blue_123 -> 2, product_blue_887 -> 7)

scala> m.filterKeys(key => s(key.split("_")(1)))
res3: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(product_orange_123 -> 1, prodoct_blue_123 -> 2, product_blue_887 -> 7)

scala> m.filter { case (k, _) => s(k.split("_")(1)) }
res4: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(product_orange_123 -> 1, prodoct_blue_123 -> 2, product_blue_887 -> 7)
```

Comment: This solution is simpler and more efficient than the accepted answer. This looks to be approximately linear, while the accepted answer is approximately quadratic.